# Crashlytics error during build-Crashlytics could not parse the resource files

Tags: android, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

Crashlytics error during build-Crashlytics could not parse the resource files

```
Error:Content is not allowed in prolog.
 WARN - Crashlytics could not parse the resources file found at C:\Users\Dell\AndroidStudioProjects\Shmoti_v4\app\src\main\res\values\._colors.xml
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:257)
```

[image]

Comment: it seems like your colors.xml inside resource folder is named wrong

Comment: please b sure that your colors.xml file is as under resource\values\colors.xml @gurudatt

Comment: This Error arises only when the crashlytics is installed and it automatically adds code at 3 places..otherwise the build is successful and we can run the app